# NodeJS, using Multer to upload multiple photos, but the last photo overwrites all the others

Tags: node.js, image-uploading, multer

I'm using NodeJS and multer to upload 1 or more photos in a specific folder. When I upload 1 photo, it works fine. When I try to upload 2 or more photos, they are uploaded in the specific folder but the last photo overwrites all the others (they maintain the correct name, but the photo content just get overwritten).

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (request, file, callback) {
        //tag and path are 2 function to set the name and path directory

        //tag example = ['IV190', '207401_SITRASB', '7738_IV19001G10101']
        var tag = file.originalname.split('-');

        //path example = "C:/progetti/sios4_nodejs/SIOS4_siosnew/Documentale/
                       //Commesse/207401_SITRASB/Opere/IV190/foto"
        var path = commons.getImagesPath(tag[0], tag[1], false);

        mkdirp.sync(path)

        return callback(null, path);
    },
    filename: function (request, file, callback) {
        //Example filename: 7738_IV19001G111.jpg
        var tag = file.originalname.substr(file.originalname.lastIndexOf('-') + 1);
        return callback(null, tag)
    }
});

var upload = multer({storage: storage});

router.post('/:inspectiongroup_id/reportingpictures/upload',
                   upload.array('files'), function (req, res) {

       return models.sequelize.transaction(function (t) {
           //....few inserts in dB, nothing related to multer and upload

           res.json({status: 'ok', message: 'Pictures uploaded'});
       });
});
```

I don't why the last one overwrites the other pictures...any clue? 
Thanks in advance. 
EDIT: 
This is the commons.getImagesPath(tag[0], tag[1], false), where

```
tag[0] = 'IV190'   //building_code in the function
tag[1] = '207401_SITRASB'   //ori_code in the function
config.images_root_folder = "C:/progetti/sios4_nodejs/SIOS4_siosnew/Documentale/Commesse"

                                                        //false
commons.getImagesPath = function(building_code,ori_code, thumb){
    if(thumb)
        return config.images_root_folder +'/'+ori_code+'/Opere/'+building_code+'/Thumbnail'; 
    else
        return config.images_root_folder +'/'+ori_code+'/Opere/'+building_code+'/foto'; 
}
```

Comment: What do your file names look like? You seem to be chopping them up to generate filenames for your files - maybe it's writing the same file over and over?

Comment: @Kryten a filename example is "7738_IV19001G111.jpg"...filenames are different, I generate them dinamically and in the destination folder, they are all different (as i generated them)

Answer (score 0):

Hi your path have some problem

I tried the below its working

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (request, file, callback) {
      //tag and path are 2 function to set the name and path directory

      //tag example = ['IV190', '207401_SITRASB', '7738_IV19001G10101']
      var tag = file.originalname.split('-');

      //path example = "C:/progetti/sios4_nodejs/SIOS4_siosnew/Documentale/
                     //Commesse/207401_SITRASB/Opere/IV190/foto"
      var path = "C:/my_projects/test/images" ;

      return callback(null, path);
  },
  filename: function (request, file, callback) {
      //Example filename: 7738_IV19001G111.jpg
      var tag = file.originalname.substr(file.originalname.lastIndexOf('-') + 1);
      return callback(null, tag)
  }
});

var upload = multer({storage: storage});

app.post('/upload',
                   upload.array('files'), function (req, res) {

           console.log("done");         

           res.json({status: 'ok', message: 'Pictures uploaded'});

});
```

Please check the postman response below.

[image]

Comment: I tried to change the path as you said (C:\ImageTest) but it generates the same error...different names, different values, but all pics get overwrited by the last pic uploaded

Comment: try to use the same code which I have shared you.Check if it is working then change  as per your requirement. I tired myself its working.

Comment: I did, the same code...still nothing, last photo just overwrites all the others

Comment: change your image selection. May be because of image name your getting confused.

Comment: Do you mean the html upload of the image? Or what else?

Comment: test with postman,If it is working then you have to check the front end

Comment: https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/ download postman using this link.

Comment: Still no...I can't use postman with my work enviroment and I can't test it at home

Answer (score 0):

I've confirmed that it works fine with the following code:

```
const mkdirp = require("mkdirp");
const path = require("path");
const app = require("express")();
const multer = require("multer");

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(_req, file, done) {
    const tag = file.originalname.split("-");

    const dir = path.join(__dirname, ...tag.slice(0, tag.length-1));
    mkdirp.sync(dir);

    return done(null, dir);
  },
  filename: function(_req, file, done) {
    const filename = file.originalname.substr(file.originalname.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
    return done(null, filename);
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

app.post("/images", upload.array("images"), function(req, res) {
  res.json({ status: "ok", message: "Pictures uploaded" });
});

app.listen("3000", () => console.log("Listening on :3000"));
```

The only difference between your code and the code above is `commons.getImagesPath(tag[0], tag[1], false);` and I suggest that you check this method if it is working as expected. (I can only suspect that part of the code.)

Comment: I edited the post with the commons.getImagesPath function...it just replace building_code and ori_code in a path, I use it to code quickly, but I don't see any problem in there